# Scaling concurrent exports of BigQuery tables to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to run a query in BigQuery and store the results in Cloud Storage. This is rather straight forward to do using BigQueries API.

An issue comes up when I try to do this with multiple queries concurrently. "Extracting" the result table to Cloud Storage slows down significantly the more tables I try to extract. Here's a summary result of an experiment I did for 20 concurrent jobs. Results are in seconds.

```
job 013 done. Query: 012.0930221081. Extract: 009.8582818508. Signed URL: 000.3398022652
job 000 done. Query: 012.1677722931. Extract: 010.7060177326. Signed URL: 000.3358650208
job 002 done. Query: 009.5634860992. Extract: 014.2841088772. Signed URL: 000.3027939796
job 004 done. Query: 011.7068181038. Extract: 012.5938670635. Signed URL: 000.2734949589
job 020 done. Query: 009.8888399601. Extract: 015.4054799080. Signed URL: 000.3903510571
job 022 done. Query: 012.9012901783. Extract: 013.9143507481. Signed URL: 000.3490731716
job 014 done. Query: 012.8500978947. Extract: 015.0055649281. Signed URL: 000.2981300354
job 006 done. Query: 011.6835210323. Extract: 016.2601530552. Signed URL: 000.2789318562
job 001 done. Query: 013.4435272217. Extract: 015.2819819450. Signed URL: 000.2984759808
job 005 done. Query: 012.0956349373. Extract: 018.9619371891. Signed URL: 000.3134548664
job 018 done. Query: 013.6754779816. Extract: 020.0537509918. Signed URL: 000.3496448994
job 011 done. Query: 011.9627509117. Extract: 025.1803772449. Signed URL: 000.3009829521
job 008 done. Query: 015.7373569012. Extract: 136.8249070644. Signed URL: 000.3158171177
job 023 done. Query: 013.7817242146. Extract: 148.2014479637. Signed URL: 000.4145238400
job 012 done. Query: 014.5390141010. Extract: 151.3171939850. Signed URL: 000.3226230145
job 007 done. Query: 014.1386809349. Extract: 160.1254091263. Signed URL: 000.2966897488
job 021 done. Query: 013.6751790047. Extract: 162.8383400440. Signed URL: 000.3162341118
job 019 done. Query: 013.5642910004. Extract: 163.2161693573. Signed URL: 000.2765989304
job 003 done. Query: 013.8807480335. Extract: 165.1014308929. Signed URL: 000.3309218884
job 024 done. Query: 013.5861997604. Extract: 182.0707099438. Signed URL: 000.3331830502
job 009 done. Query: 013.5025639534. Extract: 199.4397711754. Signed URL: 000.4156360626
job 015 done. Query: 013.7611100674. Extract: 230.2218120098. Signed URL: 000.2913899422
job 016 done. Query: 013.4659759998. Extract: 285.7284781933. Signed URL: 000.3109869957
job 017 done. Query: 019.2001299858. Extract: 322.5298812389. Signed URL: 000.2890429497
job 010 done. Query: 014.7132742405. Extract: 363.8596160412. Signed URL: 000.6748869419
```

A job does three things

1. Submits a query to BigQuery
2. Extracts the results table to Cloud Storage
3. Generate a Signed URL of the blob in Cloud Storage

As the results show, the first group of Extracts takes 9 - 25 seconds, after that it starts taking much longer.

Any ideas on why this is happening? Is this the reason? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-rate
Is there any way of fixing this?

EDIT: Here's some additional information I discovered.

```
| job | Local Extract timed | Google Extract timed | Google's Extract started | Google's Extract ended | Local Extract start | Local Extract start | 
| --- | ------------------- | -------------------- | ------------------------ | ---------------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 026 | 009.26328           | 008.84300            | 13:39:00.441000          | 13:39:09.284000        | 07:39:00.235970     | 07:39:09.498784     |
| 009 | 011.52299           | 008.04000            | 13:39:00.441000          | 13:39:08.481000        | 07:39:00.234297     | 07:39:11.756788     |
| 004 | 010.35730           | 008.66700            | 13:39:03.436000          | 13:39:12.103000        | 07:39:03.240466     | 07:39:13.597328     |
| 011 | 011.86404           | 009.29900            | 13:39:03.055000          | 13:39:12.354000        | 07:39:02.893600     | 07:39:14.756887     |
| 006 | 012.50416           | 011.75400            | 13:39:02.854000          | 13:39:14.608000        | 07:39:02.623032     | 07:39:15.126790     |
| 000 | 013.30535           | 008.77000            | 13:39:02.056000          | 13:39:10.826000        | 07:39:01.863548     | 07:39:15.168434     |
| 002 | 011.47199           | 008.53700            | 13:39:04.443000          | 13:39:12.980000        | 07:39:04.236455     | 07:39:15.708005     |
| 032 | 015.68229           | 009.69200            | 13:39:02.915000          | 13:39:12.607000        | 07:39:02.768185     | 07:39:18.450160     |
| 001 | 017.46480           | 009.35800            | 13:39:01.313000          | 13:39:10.671000        | 07:39:01.071540     | 07:39:18.535896     |
| 012 | 019.02242           | 008.65700            | 13:39:00.903000          | 13:39:09.560000        | 07:39:00.727101     | 07:39:19.749070     |
| 018 | 016.95632           | 009.75800            | 13:39:03.259000          | 13:39:13.017000        | 07:39:03.080580     | 07:39:20.036199     |
| 019 | 017.24428           | 008.51100            | 13:39:03.773000          | 13:39:12.284000        | 07:39:03.575118     | 07:39:20.819042     |
| 008 | 019.55018           | 009.83600            | 13:39:02.110000          | 13:39:11.946000        | 07:39:01.905548     | 07:39:21.455273     |
| 023 | 016.64131           | 008.94500            | 13:39:05.282000          | 13:39:14.227000        | 07:39:05.041235     | 07:39:21.682086     |
| 017 | 019.39104           | 007.12700            | 13:39:03.118000          | 13:39:10.245000        | 07:39:02.896256     | 07:39:22.286485     |
| 020 | 019.96283           | 010.05000            | 13:39:03.115000          | 13:39:13.165000        | 07:39:02.942562     | 07:39:22.904864     |
| 036 | 022.05831           | 010.51200            | 13:39:02.626000          | 13:39:13.138000        | 07:39:02.461061     | 07:39:24.518903     |
| 024 | 028.39538           | 008.79600            | 13:39:05.151000          | 13:39:13.947000        | 07:39:04.916194     | 07:39:33.311248     |
| 007 | 107.36010           | 010.68900            | 13:40:31.555000          | 13:40:42.244000        | 07:39:03.050049     | 07:40:50.409359     |
| 028 | 120.63134           | 009.52400            | 13:40:49.915000          | 13:40:59.439000        | 07:39:02.941202     | 07:41:03.572094     |
| 033 | 120.78268           | 009.54200            | 13:40:27.147000          | 13:40:36.689000        | 07:39:04.152378     | 07:41:04.934602     |
| 037 | 122.64949           | 008.80400            | 13:40:33.298000          | 13:40:42.102000        | 07:39:06.500587     | 07:41:09.149629     |
| 035 | 125.35254           | 009.13200            | 13:40:27.600000          | 13:40:36.732000        | 07:39:04.295941     | 07:41:09.647836     |
| 015 | 139.13287           | 011.17800            | 13:40:27.116000          | 13:40:38.294000        | 07:39:03.406321     | 07:41:22.538701     |
| 029 | 141.21037           | 008.23700            | 13:40:24.271000          | 13:40:32.508000        | 07:39:03.816588     | 07:41:25.026438     |
| 013 | 145.94239           | 009.19400            | 13:40:33.809000          | 13:40:43.003000        | 07:39:03.375451     | 07:41:29.317454     |
| 039 | 149.92807           | 009.72300            | 13:40:33.090000          | 13:40:42.813000        | 07:39:03.635156     | 07:41:33.562607     |
| 016 | 166.26505           | 010.12000            | 13:40:39.999000          | 13:40:50.119000        | 07:39:03.383215     | 07:41:49.647907     |
| 010 | 210.61908           | 011.37900            | 13:42:20.287000          | 13:42:31.666000        | 07:39:03.702486     | 07:42:34.321079     |
| 027 | 227.83011           | 010.00900            | 13:42:25.845000          | 13:42:35.854000        | 07:39:02.953435     | 07:42:50.783106     |
| 025 | 228.48326           | 009.71000            | 13:42:20.845000          | 13:42:30.555000        | 07:39:03.673122     | 07:42:52.155934     |
| 022 | 244.57685           | 010.06900            | 13:42:53.712000          | 13:43:03.781000        | 07:39:03.963936     | 07:43:08.540307     |
| 021 | 263.74717           | 009.81400            | 13:42:40.211000          | 13:42:50.025000        | 07:39:04.505016     | 07:43:28.251864     |
| 031 | 273.96990           | 008.55100            | 13:43:18.645000          | 13:43:27.196000        | 07:39:03.618419     | 07:43:37.587862     |
| 034 | 280.96174           | 010.53300            | 13:42:58.364000          | 13:43:08.897000        | 07:39:04.313498     | 07:43:45.274962     |
| 030 | 281.76029           | 008.27100            | 13:42:49.448000          | 13:42:57.719000        | 07:39:03.832644     | 07:43:45.592592     |
| 005 | 288.15577           | 009.85300            | 13:43:04.825000          | 13:43:14.678000        | 07:39:04.006553     | 07:43:52.161888     |
| 003 | 296.52279           | 009.65300            | 13:43:24.041000          | 13:43:33.694000        | 07:39:03.831264     | 07:44:00.353715     |
| 038 | 380.01783           | 008.45000            | 13:44:57.326000          | 13:45:05.776000        | 07:39:03.055733     | 07:45:23.073209     |
| 014 | 397.05841           | 008.99800            | 13:44:48.577000          | 13:44:57.575000        | 07:39:03.132323     | 07:45:40.190302     |
```

The table shows the amount of time I have to wait locally to run my jobs, and shows how long Google takes to do my jobs. Looking at the times, it shows that it doesn't take very long for Google to perform the extract, but it won't run the jobs at the same time, and thus will force some extracts to wait a few minutes before starting.

Comment: There's some improvement to the pipeline rolled out yesterday, if you are still blocked you can maybe try again and see if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Reran some of my tests and it's much faster now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, there is currently an internal limit on how fast export jobs are processed internally. This was originally put in to protect the system of too many long and expensive exports running in parallel. However as you noted, this limit doesn't seem to help in your case where you have many export jobs all completed within 1 minutes.

We have an open (internal) bug to address this to make the situation better for smaller exports like yours. In the mean time, if you think you're blocked by this, file a bug or let me know your project ID, we can help raise the limit for your project.